# port issue in cordova with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, socket.io

I am a UI front end Developer, not familiar with server side and port connections.
I have created a node server.js file like,

```
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
        console.log(msg);
      });
});

http.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("server starting on: "+port);
});
```

index.html head

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
    <title></title>

    <script src="lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/sio-client/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/angular-socket-io/socket.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  </head>
```

inside controller.js

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
  //code
})
```

It is working in my local system and able to work with socket chat.
But when I created cordova apk, and installed in my mobile, the chat functionality is not working.

What would be the reason?

Comment: Could be a lot of things going on here, can you post any of your client Cordova code including your Content Security Policy meta tag in the head of your index.html and any code in the Cordova app that's making Ajax requests.  Also what do you see in the Chrome/Safari console when debugging your app connected to the remote inspector?

Comment: I have updated, Please check the question above.

Answer (score 1):

You try use unsafe port and get ERR_UNSAFE_PORT. 
In your case, 8080 is unsafe port. 
Change it to 80 or 443 in server side:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 80;
```

Or run your Node.js server like this:

```
PORT=80 node server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap) guide with multiple ways to debug your Cordova application.

Because Cordova uses Webkit to render your application in Android, you can debug it in chrome remote debugger tool.

To do that check [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging) page.